# Compute integral with residue theorem

Tags: residue-calculus, complex-integration

I have the following integral
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
And a hint: integrate $\frac{e^{2iz}-1-2iz}{z^2}$ within a semi circle. But this function residue zero (what I understand as the coefficient of 1/z) what am I missing?

Comment: Hint: it can't have "no residue".  It could be that the residue is zero.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant

Comment: Then what exactly is your question?  Residue zero is no different from any other residue, as far as calculating integrals goes.

Comment: How am I supposed to compute the integral when I have $\oint f(z) \mathrm{d}z=0$?. Then I would have that $\int_{R} f(z) \mathrm{d}z = - \int_{C} f(z) \mathrm{d}z$ where $R$ is the real axis and $C$ is half the circumference... Isn't it more complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Brief solution**.  Consider the integral of the entire function
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{2iz}-1-2iz}{z^2}\ \hbox{for $z\ne0$}\ ,\quad f(0)=-2$$
around a contour consisting of $C_1$, the line from $-R$ to $R$, and $C_2$, the upper semicircle from $R$ to $-R$.

For the reasons given in your question,
$$\int_{C_1\cup C_2} f(z)\,dz=0\ .$$
Now
$$\int_{C_2}f(z)\,dz=\int_{C_2}\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}\,dz-2i\int_{C_2}\frac{dz}z\ .$$
The first integral goes to zero as $R\to\infty$ and the second is evaluated by parametrisation.  Also
$$\int_{C_1} f(z)\,dz$$
can be evaluated in terms of the integral you want, and this solves the problem.

I'll leave you to work out the details.

Comment: Thank you! That's the step I was missing

Answer (score 1):

Let,

$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(ax)dx}{x^2}$$

$$\frac{dI}{da}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2ax)dx}{x}=\pi$$

$$ I(a)=\pi a+ C$$

$$I(a)=\pi a$$ because $I(0)=0$.Hence for your particular case the answer is $ \pi /2$

Comment: How do you know $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(2ax)/x dx$ is equal to $\pi$?

Comment: @ASKASK Correct,Edited.We've to use Residue theorem

Comment: Thank you! But I had to use residue theorem

Comment: @RubénTobar Here also you need residue theorem for showing that   $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2ax)dx}{x}=\pi$.Anyways,You're welcome!